# incompatible types: java.util.lang.String cannot be converted to stringdemo.String

Tags: java

I am new to Java and about halfway through my first Java course. This weeks lab assignment instructions are:

1. Create a New Project named StringDemo
2. Write a method called `backward()` that accepts a String object as an argument and displays its contents backward. For instance, if the string argument is “*gravity*” the method should display -“*ytivarg*”. Demonstrate the method in a program that asks the user to input a string and then passes it to the method.
3. Write a method called `wordCount()` that accepts a String object as an argument and returns the number of words it contains. In this case, we will assume blank spaces separate words.  For instance, if the argument is “Four score and seven years ago” the method should return the number 6. Demonstrate the method in a program that asks the user to input a string and then passes it to the method. The number of words in the string should be displayed on the screen.  (Hint: the `split()` String method could be useful.)

I am currently on problem 2, but I am receiving this error on my keyboard input line:

> incompatible types: java.util.lang.String cannot be converted to
>   stringdemo.String

Can someone please tell me how to correct this?

Thank you.

```
import java.util.*;

public class StringDemo {
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input;

        // Create a Scanner object for keyboard input
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Get user input
        System.out.print("Enter a word or phrase to be reversed: ");
        input = keyboard.nextLine();

        // Reverse the input using StringBuilder
        StringBuilder input1 = new StringBuilder();
        input1.append(input);
        input1 = input1.reverse();

        for (int i = 0; i < input1.length(); i++)
            System.out.print(input1.charAt(i));
    }

}
```

Comment: I am able to run the program and get the expected output. How are you compiling and running the code?

(As an aside, I don't think you should use the built-in reverse method for your homework)

Comment: Did you make a class named `String` in package `stringdemo`? That will conflict with `java.lang.String` just like the error says.

Comment: change the line where you declare `input` to: `java.lang.String input;`

Comment: @Bajal Why not use the built-in reverse method? How else should I run the code?

Comment: @danw I did not make a class named String

Comment: @SashaSalauyou I changed the line to what you said, but now when I try to run, it says class wasn't found.

Comment: @Scuuuba_Steve when does it say this? What is exact exception or message? Do you have JRE library on classpath?

Comment: @SashaSalauyou When I hit run project, the exact message is: stringdemo.StringDemo class wasn't found in StringDemo project. Select main class: <no main classes found> I'm not sure what JRE library is.

Comment: @Scuuuba_Steve how do you run the project? From IDE or command line?

Comment: @SashaSalauyou I use NetBeans IDE 8.1

Comment: @Scuuuba_Steve - what I meant was, probably the intent behind the exercise is to learn about using arrays, so if you use `reverse()`, it does not serve the purpose. It's upto your evaluator though http://www.programmingsimplified.com/java/source-code/java-program-reverse-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove or rename your `stringdemo.String` class. Java linking rules dictate that classes in the same package are matched before the language classes, which means your

```
String input;
```

is being interpreted as

```
stringdemo.String input;
```

and not as

```
java.lang.String input;
```

Comment: another solution is to declare `input` as `java.lang.String`.

Comment: another solution, don't reuse the same name as common classes in Java, unless you like confusion.

Comment: @PeterLawrey exactly like did awt developers with their `java.awt.List` :)

Comment: The first step to the exercise is to create a new project named StringDemo. Is there a way around this?

Comment: @Scuuuba_Steve You can have a project named StringDemo (the problem isn't the project or package name). You just either need to always using fully-qualified names, or not create classes with the same name as unqualified java language classes.

Comment: @Darth Android Thank you! I renamed the project to StrDemo. Not sure why my professor would ask us to do this but I will let him know it would not compile. Thanks everyone for your help.